# OCaml check if a list is sorted

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml, sorting

need help on checking weather list is sorted in ocaml

does this work?

```
let issorted x = match x with 
    [] -> true
    | _::[] -> true
    | _::_ -> issorted_helper (x)
;; 

let rec issorted_helper x = match x with
    | [] -> true
    | h::t ->
        if h > t
            false
        else
            issorted_helper(t)
;;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an odd way to ask your question. Have you tried your code? By eye, it looks to me like it won't compile. Hint: you're using the `>` operator to compare values of two different types.

**Update**

Since you say you don't have access to OCaml yet, I'd say you should wait until you do. It's not so useful for us to act as your compiler! This code is very close, you'll get it working quickly once you have your OCaml.

Comment: why will this not compile? i don't have access to my machine yet. assuming head and tail are homogeneous?

Comment: Lists are homogeneous, but the head and tail aren't the same type. For a list of type `'a list`, the head is of type `'a` and the tail is of type '`a list`.

Comment: Guys, don't forget that we now have top-level in the browser! Check this out: http://try.ocamlpro.com/